# potential leak of an object stored into address book

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management, ios6, core-foundation

I got issue potential leak of an object stored into address book, how to resolve it.

I create address book **locally** and then copyArrayofAllpeople to people1 array. people1 array used outside of method. So where should I release **addressbookref**. Please make suggestions.

This is my code

```
 ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
    people1 = (__bridge NSArray *)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
```

Comment: After you passed to outside method, did you retained that object?

Answer (score 0):

Use  `CFRelease()` method.

```
 ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
 people1 = (__bridge NSArray *)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
  CFRelease(addressBook);
```

I think it will be helpful to you.

Comment: after putting 3rd line it get crash because of while use people1 array outside of method .   ABMultiValueRef multi = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty); multi object not created .